# WSL in Corporate Environment with Proxy and Certificates

Tags: windows, ubuntu, proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vpn

Things work a little better with base Windows, but largely fail in WSL. Because of the VPN, I cannot do name resolution (usually), can't access non HTTP based services and cannot do a system update. At one point I got more on WSL to work, but I got blocked on the internal certificates needed. I have to have WSL accept corporate certificates allowing the MITM, otherwise packages do not validate.

My company uses Checkpoint VPN. I'm not an administrator, so I cannot change their supplied options, though I do have Windows admin access.

| Command | No VPN | With VPN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cmd.exe ping google.com | Resolves name and successfully pings | Resolves name and successfully pings |
| cmd.exe curl -L google.com | Successfully resolves, handles redirect and fetches page | Successfully pings |
| wsl ping google.com | Temporary failure in name resolution | Sucessfully resolves, handles redirect and fetches page |
| wsl curl -L google.com | Could not resolve host: google.com | Could not resovle host: google.com |
| wsl apt-get update -y | Failed to resolve repos like archive.ubuntu.com | Failed to resovle repos like archive.ubuntu.com |

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
naemserver 172.28.144.1
```

```
# ip addr
2: etho <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>mtu 1350 qdisc_mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:15:5d:1d:35:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.28.155.217/20 brd 172.28.159.255 scope global etho0
 valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Where do I globally tell WSL which certificates to use and which proxy to use?